# WebView on Nougat+ doesn't render or load page

Tags: android, webview

It was working previously, but after update chrome application. Webview not rendering the page.

Comment: It's a static html or you are trying to open a real page? You should add more info to your question

Comment: go to `chrome://inspect` on a computer ...and maybe add some more information to your question, because I cannot confirm that there would be a general issue with that.

Comment: it is a checkoput page which load dynamically into the android application.

Answer (score 0):

In my 7.1.1 tablet, It works.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: WebSettings webSettings = checkoutWebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        checkoutWebview.clearCache(true);
        checkoutWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(getActivity()), "checkout");
        checkoutWebview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        checkoutWebview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        checkoutWebview.clearCache(true);

Comment: which url do you want to load page?

Comment: it is checkout page .